# Why is the notion of similarity rarely discussed in philosophy when it underpins almost all forms of argument?

Tags: induction

You cannot have any sort of inductive argument without having some sort of base set to make an inductive reference from. But choosing elements in that set requires some notion of them being similar to each other. But similar in what respect? Then, you must show that the new object you are making an inductive reference about is similar to that base set. Again, similar in what respect? These questions are clearly fundamental to induction. Of course, the notion of similarity is also fundamental to any argument from analogy for the same reason. Most of philosophy deals with whether induction is valid but induction can't even **get off the ground** without considering answers to these questions. It is almost as if the answers to these questions are presumed.

Even the classical inductive case of all swans being black implying the next one being black **presumes** that the similarity we are talking about is with respect to a property of being a swan, but clearly each black swan in that set would be unique. The property of being a swan involves ignoring differences among those animals and focusing on what is similar between those animals, but similar in what respects?

Induction is often the basis of almost all arguments that are used to figure out the truth about the world. And the truth about the world is often what we care about the most. Why then is there such little philosophical talk about what makes an object similar to another? There is a good amount of psychological research on this subject yet barely any to be found in philosophy apart from the more recent philosophers such as Nelson Goodman.

How did such a fundamental concept escape the minds of ancient philosophers?

Comment: What makes objects similar to each other is called [kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/) and [properties/universals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#PropBasiIdea). And they are discussed to death. SEP's entry on kinds (linked above) and [IEP's on properties](https://iep.utm.edu/properties/) even have multiple occurrences of the word "similarity" itself.

Comment: There were four, roughly 1500 paged, books on the human retina. I gave up, but you ain't me.

Comment: Not sure whether I can blow my own trumpet here, but the issue features in Sec. 2.2 and to some extent 3 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.05748.pdf

Comment: This is a very misinformed question. Questions of unities, forms, natures, essences, etc. run throughout all of philosophical history. From Heraclitus' quip about stepping into the **same** river twice to modern questions of relative identity, the concept of equivalence relations (and the concept of equivalence as a different notion than equality) has been plentifully analyzed and debated (though c.f. David Lewis, who claimed that the concept of identity is actually *not* puzzling at all).

Comment: @ChristianHennig Please blow your own trumpet! We need quality contributions :-) I have a tangential questions about properties and universals. When people talk of "redness", in terms of modern physics, we know there are atoms whose electrons transition between orbitals producing photons of a certain wavelength that come to our eyes - does that change the debate about the universals "red"?

Comment: @KristianBerry I agree. What about the logic behind similar triangles in math?? The assumption that philosophy does not discuss similarity is simply wrong.

Comment: I believe there are 3 triangle similarity theorms

Comment: Similarities may require not getting caught up in empirical measuring.  The similarities of irrational numbers was revealed not by measuring but by thinking much less empirically, beyond appearances.

Comment: The responses here don’t address the notion of similarity at all. @KristianBerry Heraclitus’s quip was about showing that a river is always changing. It wasn’t to discuss what makes our mind think that one object is similar to another

Comment: Your examples @Conifold contain many instances of how certain objects are perceived similarly and then grouped into kinds. Your article is specific to the question of whether certain objects are considered similar because of human interest or because they reflect nature. This is different from what process makes two objects similar or different in one’s mind and what respects are important when it comes to things like induction. These things were only addressed later by people like Goodman

Comment: @thinkingman if you think that equivalence relations, relative identity, natural kinds, Plato's Forms as being what particulars are *similar* to, etc. aren't relevant to the metaphysics of similarity, then I must have no idea what you mean by "similarity."

Comment: If objects are grouped together by natural properties or subjective dispositions then *those are* exactly what "makes objects similar in one’s mind". We may use "intuitions" initially to roughly identify such properties or dispositions, but they become irrelevant once those are subjected to systematic study. The latter does not "presume" them at all, it tests and sorts them out. Goodman argued that grouping is highly context sensitive and philosophically unilluminating in general, which is a typical nominalist position. There is nothing "apart" about it except for high quality of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Such things are commonly discussed by philosophers. The issue goes back at least as far as Plato with his theory of forms and Aristotle with his distinction between essential and accidental properties.

In more recent work, the issue is usually discussed in the context of questions about [universals and properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/), e.g. whether universals are real and correspond to [natural kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/), or whether they are just nominal distinctions.

To some extent, we can make use of the fact that we are the product of natural selection, and if we weren't good at making distinctions our species would not have survived. It is vital to be able to recognise and distinguish the similarities between tigers and the similarities between sheep and the differences between tigers and sheep. Humans are good at such things and would not have prospered without that capacity.

But such similarities only take us so far. In the context of inductive reasoning, Nelson Goodman pointed out that projecting properties and relations from observed cases to unobserved ones always involves focusing on some properties and not others. The future always resembles the past in some respects and not others: the trick is to work out which ones matter. Relying on similarity of appearance can easily be deceptive in this respect. In science, sometimes things may appear similar but be significantly different, or appear different but be similar in some important way. Distinguishing the important similarities from the rest requires a great deal of scientific hard labour.

It is not just inductive reasoning that depends on understanding similarity. Deductive logic does also. One can write a formula such as (∀x)(Fx ⊃ Gx) but what exactly do F and G mean? They may be clearcut in simple mathematical examples, but as soon as we try to apply a formula to real things and properties, we need to be able to specify what is included and what is not. If we want to use that formula to represent the proposition "all people are mortal" then what exactly is a person and what exactly is mortal?

I sometimes wonder whether, in the last analysis, all reasoning isn't just reasoning by analogy.

Comment: That's the conclusion of Hofstadter and Sander in [Surfaces and Essences: Analogy as the Fuel and Fire of Thinking (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=92e30rzcoCkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=analogies+hoffstater&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQwba-x-b9AhXwCjQIHUVrBuMQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=analogies%20hoffstater&f=false) as well as cognitive semanticists who see the [conceptual metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor) which purports the subconscious faculties of intuition are mappings from source to target domains of bodily experience...

Comment: Dale Purvis makes the same argument from neurology in [Brains as Engines of Association (GB)](https://books.google.com/books?id=GmE7uwEACAAJ&dq=engine+of+association&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG4saW7d78AhUBjIkEHUEeCjIQ6AF6BAgFEAI). Messy and extended analogies are the norm, and tidy logical formalisms are mere abstractions that simplify to the point of formal system to make it syntactically rigorous at the expense of accurate to a domain of discourse.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of geometry deals with the concepts of similarity. What makes a line segment equal to another? What makes a line similar to another? What makes one triangle equal to another. What makes a triangle similar to another. These relations are expressed as equations. All circles have the same equation. Similar circles have different values for the equation variables. Euclid was doing this as early as 300 BC.

Comment: No need to single out geometry. "Similarity" is pervasive throughout mathematics, in various forms.

Comment: @Frank I agree. I choose geometry because it is one of oldest and easiest to visualize.

Comment: This isn’t a case of the similarity I am talking about. This is just a case of definitions and seeing whether an object fits that definition. There is no need for a concept of similarity here when what defines a circle is mathematical

Comment: @thinkingman Two circles with different radii are two non-identical circles. Cant two non-identical circles be similar to each other? Isn't this similarity a function of radius and position?

Comment: @thinkingman A mathematical circle is an ideal object. All physical circles are just similarities to the ideal.

Comment: @thinkingman In engineering this similarity is quantified as tolerances which is simply the allowable deviation from the ideal. A circle with radius = 5.0 + /- 0.1 cm means that two similar circles can be identical as long as this criterion is met